# PHP: Really confusing $this "glitch" when called within a statically-called method

Tags: php, static, scope, this

This is one of those "my code works, I don't know why" times.

I have a method in an instantiated class that statically calls a method of what is basically a static class. I say "basically" because while coding it I neglected to declare the methods of the class exclusively static. The method in question belongs to the first class but I blindly copy/pasted the code (which was originally internal) and didn't quite update everything, so the $this-> remained even though the method doesn't belong to the class it's within.

So, basically I had this:

```
class MyClass{
    public function callOtherMethod(){
        OtherClass::otherMethod();
    }
    public function myMethod(){
        echo 'Tada!';
    }
}

class OtherClass{
    public function otherMethod(){
        echo get_class($this);
        $this->myMethod();
    }
}

$thing = new MyClass();
$thing->callOtherMethod();
```

This somehow worked without issue until I did some cleanup and explicitly declared the OtherClass' methods static as they were meant to be. Everything worked because, for some reason I was unaware of, $this while used within OtherClass instead references the instantiated object that called it (i.e. MyClass).

I didn't think this should be possible, should it? I know it's bad coding standards and I'm making revisions to avoid it, but I found it really, really weird.

Comment: *This is one of those "my code works, I don't know why" times* Okay, I know what you [mean](http://en.docsity.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/02/programmers-be-like.jpg)!

Comment: Only ever worked with a very few versions of PHP, and none that are currently supported: http://3v4l.org/HTDlJ

Comment: Could've sworn it was up to date on my server, guess not.

Comment: @MarkBaker err... I see on the page you linked that it works with every PHP version since 5.0. It issues a warning since 5.1.3 but because it's not an error and it doesn't stop the script it can be easily hidden/ignored/overseen. I guess it is a leftover from PHP 4.

Comment: What level of error reporting do you have in your script? If you set the error level to 'error_reporting(E_ALL);' and run the script - do you get any messages? What version of PHP are you running? I am running PHP 5.3.29 - your code triggers an 'E_STRICT' error but shows 'MyClassTada!'. To see what happens in later versions then **[codepad.viper-7.com with your code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/pQclUD)** may be useful?

Comment: I was in fact getting similar errors/warnings in the logs (version 5.3.5 on one and 5.4.36 on another), but I just was surprised it could work in the first place.